How to narrow a complex union in TypeScript by checking only part of it?
I have the following TypeScript code, describing a type that can have a specific subset of "animations" or "points":
type Register = {
  animations?: string;
  points?: string;
}

type OrString<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends string ? T[K] : string;
type RegisterAnimation<T extends Register> = OrString<T, 'animations'>;
type RegisterPoint<T extends Register> = OrString<T, 'points'>;

export interface Sprite<R extends Register> {
  setAnimation(animation: RegisterAnimation<R>): void;
  getPoint(point: RegisterPoint<R>): [number, number];
  hasAnimation<T extends RegisterAnimation<Register>, U extends T>(this: Sprite<Register & { animations: T }>, animation: U): this is Sprite<Register & { animations: U }>;
}

// Each variation has specific animations and/or points that can be set:
type A = { animations: 'walk' | 'static'; points: 'topLeft' | 'topRight' };
type B = { animations: 'run' | 'jump' };

type PossibleSprites =
  | Sprite<A>
  | Sprite<B>

The intent is that I can use the hasAnimation function to figure out which of the two PossibleSprites I actually have. And with the definitions above, it works:
function test(sprite: PossibleSprites): void {
  if (sprite.hasAnimation('run')) {
    // sprite is now a Sprite<B>
    sprite.setAnimation('run');

    // Error:
    // Argument of type '"walk"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"run" | "jump"'.
    sprite.setAnimation('walk');
  } else {
    // sprite is a Sprite<A>
    sprite.setAnimation('walk');
    sprite.getPoint('topLeft');

    // Error:
    // Argument of type '"run"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"walk" | "static"'.
    sprite.setAnimation('run');
  }
}

(Playground link for the above)
However, if I change the type definitions slightly:
type A = { animations: 'walk' | 'static'; points: 'topLeft' | 'topRight' };
type B = { animations: 'run' | 'jump'; points: 'bottom' }; // now B has points

type PossibleSprites =
  | Sprite<A>
  | Sprite<B>

... then it doesn't work anymore:
function test(sprite: PossibleSprites): void {
  if (sprite.hasAnimation('run')) {
    // sprite is now a PossibleSprites & Sprite<Register & { animations: "run"; }> :(
    sprite.setAnimation('run');

    // Error:
    // Argument of type '"walk"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"run"'.
    sprite.setAnimation('walk');
  } else {
    // sprite is now a `PossibleSprites` :(
    // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    sprite.setAnimation('walk');
    // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    sprite.getPoint('topLeft');

    // Error:
    // Argument of type '"run"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    sprite.setAnimation('run');
  }
}

(Playground link)
The code in this question is based off of the answer to possible to narrow a generic with typeguard?.
I think this is related to the fact that hasAnimation doesn't resolve anything about the points, so TypeScript decides it doesn't have enough information? But as a human looking at it I can see that, since A and B have completely different animations, that checking the animations should be enough to determine which of the two union cases my type is.
Is it possible to do this narrowing correctly, or is this a limitation in the TypeScript compiler?

I would think maybe you could do something like this playground link shows. Does that meet your needs? if so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz that looks reasonable and appears to work - could you explain why the "naive" solution that I tried doesn't work as well as why the infer keyword works?

Hmm, it's been 10 days since you posted this and it's mostly gone out of my head. I'd be happy to look at this again, but if I do so, would you be likely to reply within, say, a day or two? If not then it becomes difficult to keep track of.

@jcalz Sure - though I think it'd be best to put your explanation in an answer anyway?
